# Python Fabric stops automating commands on Cisco devices

Tags: python, fabric, cisco

I run my Fab file on over 100 devices. It goes through every device without issue, saving the output locally. However, every time it gets to a Cisco device, it will type the command in, but will not, essentially hit "ENTER". I have to manually hit "ENTER", then type "exit". It will then go onto the next command for that device, and I have to do the same thing again until it moves onto the next non Cisco device. I have no idea how to get around this. My output looks like the following:

```
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Executing task 'execute_commands'
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] run: show running-config ntp
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] out: Type help or '?' for a list of available commands.
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] out:
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] out: user12345# show running-config ntp
```

I think it may have something to do with the "Type help or '?' for a list of available commands." portion of it. That is standard on cisco devices after the banner...

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the code :) to be able to help out.

Sometimes you need to add extra "CR" Carriage Return (Hitting enter) when working with Cisco routers : file.write("\r"), you'll find a lot of posts about that.

Comment: Its ALOT of code. it does more than just run checks, and I can't exactly post it if you catch my drift.

Comment: Add a link to pastebin

Comment: What I think its doing, is trying to run the command before it actually gget all the way SSHed in. Then that "Type help or '?' for a list of available commands." and messes it up.

Comment: You are right, it can be a wide range of things: you are not on the 'enabled' mode, you are on another plane (admin or shell) with the wrong port, or your account is not authorized, so you need to make sure the script prints out the syslog/STDOut to find out what is going on ? Let me know if u need help on how ot print debug/stdout.